# Accessing nested Swift enum in Objective-C

Tags: swift, objective-c, enums, nested

I have a nested swift enum as following:

```swift
@objc enum PARENT_ENUM: Int {    
    case test
        
    @objc enum CHILD_ENUM: Int{
        case CHILD_ENUM_CASE
    }        
}
```

I want to access this enum in Objective-C. I tried the following in Objective-C:

```objectivec
PARENT_ENUMTest; // This line is working.

PARENT_ENUM.CHILD_ENUMCHILD_ENUM_CASE; // nested attempt giving error.

PARENT_ENUM.CHILD_ENUM.CHILD_ENUM_CASE; // nested attempt giving error.
```

The compiler is giving the 'Expected identifier or '('' error.

Comment: I checked an it doesn't even appear in `MyApp-Swift.h`, while parent does... It doesn't seem possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57388941/how-to-make-a-swift-enum-available-in-objective-c ?

Comment: Off-topic, but those names don't follow the Swift naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like a compiler bug, as nested types within a class are successfully exported at any levels. For example:

```swift
@objc class C1: NSObject {
    @objc class C2: NSObject {
        @objc class C3: NSObject {            
        }
    }

    @objc SomeEnum: Int {
    }
}
```

, makes available all classes/enums to Objective-C.

Until this gets fixed, a workaround would be to define both enums at the top level. The Objective-C exporter anyway flattens the hierarchy, so even if the nested enum would be available to Objective-C, it would be under the `CHILD_ENUM` name, not `PARENT_ENUM.CHILD_ENUM`, like it would need to be used in swift.

But if you really want the namespacing brought by the nesting, another workaround would be a type alias:

```swift
@objc enum ParentEnum: Int {
    typealias ChildEnum = __ChildEnum
    
    case test
}

// double underscored, to make it clearer for other to
// not directly use it
@objc(ChildEnum) enum __ChildEnum: Int {
    case childEnumCase
}
```